# Overlapping opaque shapes drawn to a graphics object within a translucent container don't show the correct alpha in the overlapping region

Tags: pixi.js

I have a PIXI.Graphics inside a PIXI.Container (along with some other stuff, including a mask, and a border). The graphics object is being used to draw various polygons. The alpha property of the Container is set to 0.5. Here is the result:

[image: Result]

The bright square is the overlap between two polygons. It seems that even though both polygons were drawn to the same opaque graphics object, it's as though they are separate objects with their own alpha channels.

Is there any way to merge all of the polygons together so that the resulting graphics will have uniform alpha despite some overlapping polygons?

Pixi version is 4.7.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this problem in general is to draw all the necessary geometry, then set `cacheAsBitmap` to true on the Graphics object.

[image]

`cacheAsBitmap` is great for graphics that don't change often, and another benefit to using it is that it speeds up rendering.

Unfortunately, it appears that there could possibly be a bug using `cacheAsBitmap` with objects that use parent layers or masks which cause all the graphics to disappear if either is set.

[image]

In my particular situation, this does not help me because I need masking. Hopefully it helps someone else though.

**Edit**

The above solution works if you put the graphics inside a container, and apply the mask to the container. I found this out by complete accident while messing around.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use `AlphaFilter` to achieve this. See this thread: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/4334

```
const colorMatrix = new filters.AlphaFilter();
colorMatrix.alpha = 0.5;
container.filters = [colorMatrix];
```